# How to change color when tapped using touchable custom paint in flutter?

Tags: flutter, canvas, paint, custom-painting

I make `sleep data chart` that has touchable bar charts. This is made by using `touchable custom painter`.
[Here](https://github.com/jja08111/Learning-Flutter/tree/main/Sleep-data-chart) is sample code, image. Tooltip that has sleep amount message is shown when you long pressed the bar.

So, I want to add **effect that change bar color when I tap down the bar**.
But I don't know how to make this effect.

I tried to add some code in `component/chart_painter.dart` but this can't change color.

```dart
//~~~ line 90
      touchyCanvas.drawRRect(rect, paint,
        onLongPressStart: (_) => showTooltipCallback(
          context: context,
          amount: dataAmount[index],
          left: left,
          top: top,
        ),
        // like this
        onTapDown: (_) {
          canvas.drawRRect(rect, paint);
        }
      );
//~~~
```